# Detener evento. preventDefault

Tags: javascript

```
function alertar() {
if 
    (confirm("¡ADVERTENCIA!.")) {
        return true;
    } else {
preventDefault();
    }
} 
    <li ><a href="/login.php" class="admidan" onclick="alertar()">ADMINISTRADOR</a></li>
```

Tengo un evento, cuando me sale la alerta necesito que al dar en cancelar se detenta, pero al dar click sigue a la pagina asignada. intente con variable en el preventDefault();, pero ya no sale la alerta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que pasarle el evento como parámetro a la función para llamar al método `preventDefault` sobre el evento.

**JS**

```
function alertar(event) {
   if 
   (confirm("¡ADVERTENCIA!.")) {
       return true;
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li ><a href="/login.php" class="admidan" onclick="alertar(event)">ADMINISTRADOR</a></li>
```

Espero que te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: Ya lo intente, y al ponerla laa funcion no la lee. Porque no me envía alerta nada.

Comment: Pues copiando y pegando el js y el html a mí me funciona

Comment: Sera por que mi doc es .php? Tiene que ver algo ?

Comment: No deberia, puedes editar el post y poner el .php entero? Muchas gracias.

Comment: saludos, ya me funcion. No estaba digitanto bien la palabra "event". Siempre debe ir esta palabra como parametros en dichos casos?

Comment: En el js puedes llamarlo como quieras ya que es un parametro, pero en el html tiene que ser event porque  le estas pasando el objeto event

Comment: Listo, gracias. algo nuevo anotado.